# Given mean and standard deviation of the number of accidents in Town A, find mean and variance in Town B.

Tags: probability, expectation, standard-deviation

I'm having some trouble figuring out this question:

> The number of car accidents in Town A has mean $2.3$
>   car accidents per hour with standard deviation of $1.5$ car accidents per
>   hour. It is known that the number of car accidents in Town B is $3$
>   times that of Town A. Given this information, what is the mean and variance of the number of car accidents in Town B?

Been stuck on this for a while and I'm just not really sure how to begin to approach this problem.

Comment: Weird problem. The interpretation $Y=3X$ is physically highly implausible. More plausible is that $Y=X_1+X_2+X_3$, where the $X_i$ have the same distribution as the $X$ for Town A, and are independent.

Comment: I agree with Andre, _but_ the author (whoever wrote the problem) should know better; '3 times that of town A' literally means $3X$. If they wanted Andre's interpretation they really should have written 'the sum of 3 iid variables'. It is very well understood that in general $3X \neq X_1+X_2+X_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of accidents in town A, and $Y$ the number in town B.
Then the relationship is 
$$Y = 3X.$$
Then, recall the properties:

1. $E[Y] = E[cX] = cE[X]$ and
2. $\text{Var}(cX) = c^2\text{Var}(X).$